# Querying a Column with multiple items in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to do a select statement like this.

```
Select motor 
From motorlist 
where motorsize = '100'
```

The issue I'm having is my motorsize column's rows have multiple items in a `nvarchar` so for example it could contain `100,101,102` in one row.

Comment: you should have a separate linking table with the various motor sizes linked to the motor.  The querying will get nasty over time if you don't.

Comment: Check out this TechNet article on database Normalization rules.  Rather than ask how to write a "bad" query, you should design a "good" database and "good" queries will follow.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216117(v=SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks, im rewriting a program at my company but the database is prettymuch out of my hands, this table is only about 10 rows anyway so its not to big of a concern for me atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select motor From motorlist where motorsize like '%100%'
```

Or safer...

```
Select motor From motorlist where ',' + motorsize + ',' like '%,100,%'
```

On side note, I do agree with comment that it's better NOT to have fields like this with multiple values, but understand you may be constarined by previous design.

in C#

```
var strSql = "Select motor From motorlist where \',\' + motorsize + \',\' like \'%," + mySearchMotorSize + ",%\'";
```

Comment: @DeadZone, it should work. Note that in the second example I add a prefix and suffix comma to the string list before using the like (where ',' + motorsize + ',' ...)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment after I realized that.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for, as a side question im querrying this database from c# and my motorsize is getting passed through.  How do you add the %% to that. Ex. '" + motorsizeval +"'

Answer (score 1):

You would use "like":

```
select motor from motorlist where motorsize like '%100%'
```

Or depending on your data you could try different things to get the where clause tuned better. For example if you didn't want to find rows with 1000 when searching for 100, you would do this:

```
select motor from motorlist where motorsize like '%100,% or motorsize like '%100'
```